# Video will not play a second time on iOS devices

Tags: ios, jquery-ui-dialog, video.js

I'm not sure what the problem is. I have a video that I'd like to play in a modal dialog.

I have everything set up and working fine on all devices. The only issue that I've been unable to overcome is that the video will not play a second time on iOS devices.

http://c4sandbox.com/video/index.html is a simple demonstration of the problem that I'm having. If you close the dialog (it will auto close when the video ends) then click the 'show again' link on an iOS device, then the video player is just an empty black box.

What am I missing? This happens in Safari and Chrome, but only on iOS.

EDIT: The problem appears to be with video.js because a straight html5 video tag will play the video multiple times as expected. Unfortunately, I need the flash fallback so html5 only is not an option.

Comment: Do you want to loop the video play or when the user taps the button then the video plays again ? Also please mention what are you using for video play.

Comment: Sorry, I added the tags and forgot to include the data in the post. I'm trying to use video.js to play the html5 video with flash fallback. The extra play button is for mobile devices which have to initiate the play action manually.

Comment: Oh, I didn't check the tags (only the iOS one), I have no idea of jquery, so sorry I can't help you :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue. The way I am getting around it is using the player's dispose() method to kill the instance and re-injecting the HTML for the player and re-instantiating it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Victor! your solution works. Since there is no example code given, here is the code I used.

```
//Init
videoPlayer = _V_("video_post", {
        controls:true,
        preload:"auto",
        autoplay:true,
}, function(){
});
```

after you're done with the player (e.g. closes the video dialog), dispose the player

```
videoPlayer.dispose();
```

Done. hope this helps.